# How to using moment.js

Tags: frontend, momentjs

I find that moment.js can format the time..

so I tested with format HH:mm

And I input 24 but I though that the output is 24:00 but I only see it's 00:00?

What can I do for showing 24:00?

Thanks

Comment: Check this answer here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811502/moment-js-24-hour-time-format-dealing-with-the-24th-hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811502/moment-js-24-hour-time-format-dealing-with-the-24th-hour)

Comment: Do you want to go from 24:59 to 01:00? Anyway... 24:00 or 24:01 is another day... this is nothing but unintuitive.

Comment: Not. I mean when I input just 24 then format to 24:00... but suddenly I found answer in the above. Thanks

Comment: @Dũng can you put my answer as correct please if suits your needs?

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov yes... but how to do it ^^ I just new to using this stackoverflow... (almost time every my question have the answer here)

Comment: You need to put green tick on the left side of my answer)